# Recycler View GridLayoutManager - Weights for each row

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager that accomplishes the following behavior:

```
  -------------
  |           |
  |           |
  -------------
  |       |   |
  |       |   |
  -------------
  |   |       |
  |   |       |
  -------------
  |       |   |
  |       |   |
  -------------
  |   |       |
  |   |       |
  -------------
```

The idea is that the first item always occupy the full row, then the next rows are divided in 3 spaces, with 2 items, with one item having a weight of 2 and the other a weight of 1 (similar to a LinearLayout).

How can I accomplish such behavior?

Comment: By implementing own `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, as Selvin suggested, I looked up custom LayoutManager and found out that overriding the method getSpanSize() would work for me.

```
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            Category item = mCategories.get(position);
            return item.weight;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But this will change only the number of spans the item occupies. It won't change the span weight itself. For example, if the total span count is 4 and this method returns 3, then the item will take 75% of the row, but the spans are still equal. Is there a way to change the weight of the span itself? That is the span count is 2 but spans weight is different?